# Como saber qual é o último item selecionado de um listView?

Tags: java, array, sqlite, listview

Olá, tenho uma `ListView` usando o `simple_list_item_multiple_choice`, preenchida com uma `ArrayString` de todos os estados brasileiros.

Preciso preencher o seguinte comando SQL com todos os estados selecionados pelo usuário através da String ufSelecionado:

```
SQL Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PALAVRAS WHERE _estado IN ("+ ufSelecionado + ")", null);
```

**Para isso estou usando o seguinte código:**

```
SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
String ufSelecionado = "";
int cntChoice = listView.getCount();

for ( int i = 0; i < (cntChoice-1); i++) {
    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
        ufSelecionado += "'"+ listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "'" + ", ";
    }

}

ufSelecionado += "'"+ listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "'";
```

O problema é que usando esse método a variável `ufSelecionado` sempre vai pegar o último item da lista mesmo quando ele não é selecionado.

Mas se eu remover o trecho que esta fora do laço:

```
ufSelecionado += "'"+ listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "'";
```

o resultado vai conter sempre uma virgula(,) após o último item selecionado o que gera erro no comando `SELECT` do sql.

Então, minha pergunta é: **Como removo a virgula apenas após o último item selecionado?**

Espero que consigam entender minha dúvida.

Comment: Em resumo, você quer sempre acrescentar a vírgula ao ufSelecionado dentro do for, exceto quando é o último item da lista?

Comment: @StatelessDev, exato, foi o que eu entendi também.

Comment: Exato, exceto porém após o último item selecionado, que não necessariamente é o último da lista.
Ex: Numa lista com os itens: (Acre, Amazonas, Amapá, Bahia, Ceará), se o usuário selecionar apenas (Amazonas, Bahia) o resultado deve ser `ufSelecionado = 'Amazonas','Bahia'`

Porém atualmente o código está retornando `ufSelecionado = 'Amazonas','Bahia','Ceará'` mesmo que o usuário não escolha o item Ceará.

E se eu tirar a linha de código fora do laço for o resultado é: `ufSelecionado = 'Amazonas','Bahia',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUALQUER que seja o valor atribuído a sua variável `ufSelecionado`, **`'Amazonas','Bahia','Ceará'`** ou **`'Amazonas','Bahia',`** a solução é simplesmente:

```
ufSelecionado = ufSelecionado.substring(0, ufSelecionado.lastIndexOf(","));
```